# Why does Tomcat read BouncyCastle Security provider jar from Tomcat/temp directory?

Tags: java, tomcat7, bouncycastle

Getting the following error log while using BC provider for decryption

Not sure why tomcat is reading the jar from tomcat/temp directory from another war(0-dca). Need input as to why is is happening

```
(2016-10-26 10:03:43,539) DEBUG [-::ajp-apr-8009-exec-18]  [abc.platform.security.PrivacyTextUtils:807] Failure to decrypt: bad encryption: E8gjVVFLOMR6nPcrLj_Kvjp2wLx57msxRqmCZw
    java.lang.SecurityException: JCE cannot authenticate the provider BC
            at javax.crypto.Cipher.getInstance(Cipher.java:657)
            at javax.crypto.Cipher.getInstance(Cipher.java:596)
            at abc.platform.security.PrivacyTextUtils$EncryptionType.getCipherInstance(PrivacyTextUtils.java:359)
    Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: Cannot verify jar:file:/opt/tomcat-7.0.59/temp/0-dca/WEB-INF/lib/bcprov-jdk16-1.46.jar!/
            at javax.crypto.JarVerifier.verifySingleJar(JarVerifier.java:407)
            at javax.crypto.JarVerifier.verifyJars(JarVerifier.java:322)
            at javax.crypto.JarVerifier.verify(JarVerifier.java:250)
            at javax.crypto.JceSecurity.verifyProviderJar(JceSecurity.java:160)
            at javax.crypto.JceSecurity.getVerificationResult(JceSecurity.java:186)
            at javax.crypto.Cipher.getInstance(Cipher.java:653)
            at javax.crypto.Cipher.getInstance(Cipher.java:596)
            at abc.platform.security.PrivacyTextUtils$EncryptionType.getCipherInstance(PrivacyTextUtils.java:359)
            at abc.platform.security.PrivacyTextUtils$EncryptionType.decrypt(PrivacyTextUtils.java:282)
            at abc.platform.security.PrivacyTextUtils.symmetricDecrypt(PrivacyTextUtils.java:796)
            at abc.platform.security.PrivacyTextUtils.symmetricDecrypt(PrivacyTextUtils.java:735)
            at abc.platform.account.impl.AccountResourceGroupSourceImpl.onChangedSection(AccountResourceGroupSourceImpl.java:148)
            at abc.platform.config.impl.ConfigManagerImpl.initConfigObject(ConfigManagerImpl.java:707)
            at abc.platform.config.impl.ConfigManagerImpl.registerConfigObject(ConfigManagerImpl.java:482)
    Caused by: java.security.PrivilegedActionException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /opt/tomcat-7.0.59/temp/0-dca/WEB-INF/lib/bcprov-jdk16-1.46.jar (No such file or directory)
            at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
            at javax.crypto.JarVerifier.verifySingleJar(JarVerifier.java:385)
            ... 48 more

    Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /opt/tomcat-7.0.59/temp/0-dca/WEB-INF/lib/bcprov-jdk16-1.46.jar (No such file or directory)
            at java.util.zip.ZipFile.open(Native Method)
            at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:220)
            at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:150)
            at java.util.jar.JarFile.<init>(JarFile.java:166)
            at java.util.jar.JarFile.<init>(JarFile.java:103)
            at sun.net.www.protocol.jar.URLJarFile.<init>(URLJarFile.java:93)
            at sun.net.www.protocol.jar.URLJarFile.getJarFile(URLJarFile.java:69)
            at sun.net.www.protocol.jar.JarFileFactory.get(JarFileFactory.java:99)
            at sun.net.www.protocol.jar.JarURLConnection.connect(JarURLConnection.java:122)
            at sun.net.www.protocol.jar.JarURLConnection.getJarFile(JarURLConnection.java:89)
            at javax.crypto.JarVerifier$2.run(JarVerifier.java:399)
            at javax.crypto.JarVerifier$2.run(JarVerifier.java:386)
            ... 50 more
```